# java FileNotFoundExcpetion when writing image

Tags: java, image, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to save an image using `Image.IO.Write()`; I have basically copied the standard code from [here](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Taking_Screen_Shots) to take screenshots with lwjgl. The only thing I did was initialize the file with an existing directory as the save path.

When I try to save the image the `FileNotFoundException` gets thrown.

```
    glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
    int width  = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int height = Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    int bpp = 4; // Assuming a 32-bit display with a byte each for red, green, blue, and alpha.
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * bpp);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    File file = new File("res/screenshots/ss_" + Sys.getTime() + ".png"); // The file to save to.
    String format = "PNG"; // Example: "PNG" or "JPG"
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            int i = (x + (width * y)) * bpp;
            int r = buffer.get(i) & 0xFF;
            int g = buffer.get(i + 1) & 0xFF;
            int b = buffer.get(i + 2) & 0xFF;
            image.setRGB(x, height - (y + 1), (0xFF << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b);
        }

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, format, file);
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res\screenshots\ss_91733792.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.va.util.Extras.takeScreenShot(Extras.java:46)
    at com.va.core.Engine.start(Engine.java:117)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.va.util.Extras.takeScreenShot(Extras.java:46)
    at com.va.core.Engine.start(Engine.java:117)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Comment: What is the problem?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Show your code .. The file part

Comment: stacktrace would be helpful aswell.

Comment: 1) verify that the directory exists, and that it's writeable.  2) Verify that Java is writing to the directory you *think* it is - your program's working directory might be *different*.  3) Try a fully qualified pathname (to debug 2), if you're in doubt) 4) make sure you specify a *filename* (as well as directory path).  5) Cut/paste the actual filepath you're using.  6) Cut/paste the exact stack trace you're seeing.

Comment: I also have this same code in 2 previous projects and it has worked fine. I try looking at my folder setup and it looks ok. I think it may be something with handling internal files.

Comment: @coder13 What 'internal files'? It is the target path not existing. Period.

Answer (score 3):

I assume "/res/screenshots" exists and is writeable, correct?

I'm guessing your program's current directory might be different than what you're expecting.

For debug purposes, please add these two lines (or equivalent):

```
  String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
  System.out.println ("Current directory: " + currentDir);
```

If "res/screenshots" is NOT under "currentDirectory", then change the relative path in your code.

```
  // EXAMPLE:
  File file = new File("../..res/screenshots/ss_" + Sys.getTime() + ".png");
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized the code that was the exact same in my previous 2 projects wasn't working because I was running it through a linked project. I have a main and api. The code is in the api and is ran through the main. the main doesn't have the folders setup so thats probably why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The code you linked to, does not show how the file is created and leaves it to the programmer.

What you are doing is probably only creating a new `File` object with

```
File img = new File("path/to/file.jpg");
```

Your problem is, the `path/to` folder does not exist, and `ImageIO` throws `FileNotFoundException`.

to make this work, use

```
img.getParent().mkdirs();
```

before you pass the `img` to `ImageIO`. This way you make sure, that the full path to the file is accessible. As stated in the comments to this post, the file itself does not have to exist, but the path to id does.

Comment: I am not sure he needs to call createNewFile(). The javadoc implies that it always throws away any file contents at the path. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29

Comment: @Colin D - I agree.  The OP shouldn't need "createNewFile()".

Comment: Thanks guys. Now the OP added a stacktrace its more obvious there is a problem with the path (folders do not exist). I've edited original answer.

Comment: @npe completely agree. nice answer.

Comment: No - what if he does a "mkdir()" in the wrong place?  And why incur the overhead of calling "mkdir()" every time you want to write a new file? "mkdir()" is not necessarily the correct approach here...

Comment: @paulsm4: Well, there are two choices. Either he's in the wrong directory (see coder13 answer) or he assumed that the `screenshot` folder exists. I don't decide where to put the `mkdirs()` but if he uses many different folders, he'd be better calling it. The influence on the performance is minimal compared to time spend in `ImageIO#write()`.